# Is it possible to use a "static" reference to self in pool.map() using Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a line of code like this:

```
pool.map(functools.partial(method_to_run, self), data)
```

`method_to_run` takes the data item and then uses an object attached to self to make a request to a server, using an instance variable of that object containing an authentication token, set earlier.

The issue I have is that each process seems to get a new instance of that object (or `self`), and therefore that instance has not had the token set and therefore the request fails.

Is there a way to share self between pooled processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: the way you describe it - no - it is not possible.

Whenever you fork a process (i.e. via creating a pool of those) all data from the memory is copied into a fork (i.e. not referenced).

As a result any mutation that you make to the original payload does not affect the fork's replica.

You have three options here:

1. Use a thread pool (threads share memory): https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
2. Employ IPC structures: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html
3. Assign the authentication token to self before you create a process pool. This will make sure that self's replica will contain the token.

Answer (score 1):

While you could do it using a manager, it means the object will be copied to all other processes every time it is modified.

I suggest passing the token itself to the process, instead of copying the entire object around. If you don't have the token available at the time you call `pool.map`, then the idiomatic idea is to create a `Queue` to send the token to your process later. Your process can sit at the other end of the `Queue` and wait for the token before issuing the request.